# Asp.net 2.0 error repeater button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to use a repeater and use ajax instead of the "`EnableEventValidation='true'`" but I get the error below on page unload. When I click  on the button in the repeater the `repeater1_ItemCommand` does not get referenced

Error:

> System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal System.ArgumentException:
>   Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page

Code:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="MainSM" EnablePageMethods="true"  runat="server" ScriptMode="Release" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate>
<table id="myTable" width="700" border="1" class = "mMMGrid" frame="box">
<th align=left>Page Image</th><th align=left>Page #</th><th align=left >Page Sequnce</th><tbody>
<tr>
  <td width="15%">
  <div id = "dPage" runat="server" >
   <asp:ImageButton ID="imbtnCourseLink" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%#imPath(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ChunkFilePath"))%>' OnClick="imlink2"  Width="75px"  Height="75px"  /> 

    </div>
    </td>
    <td width="15%">
    <strong>Pages</strong> : <asp:label ID="lblPage" Text='<%# Eval("Page")%>' runat="server"></asp:label> <br/>
     </td>
     <td width="65%"> 
      <asp:ImageButton ID="imbtUp" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/SiteImages/go-up.png" Width="40" height="40" CommandName="UP" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Page")%>'/>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="imbtDown" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/SiteImages/go-down.png" Width="40" Height="40" />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <triggers>
    <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="imbtUp" eventname="Click" />
       <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="Repeater1" eventname="ItemCommand" />
    </triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br /> 

 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Please show your code behind especially in `Page` related events, seems that you need to re-bind the repeater's `DataSource` for every postback made.

Comment: Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemCommand
        If e.CommandName = "UP" Then
            MessageBox("122")
        End If
End Sub
Public Sub imbtUpFuncClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
       MessageBox("1200")
End Sub
Public Sub MessageBox(ByVal strMsg As String)
        Dim lbl As New Label
        lbl.Text = "<script language='javascript'>" & Environment.NewLine _
                   & "window.alert(" & "'" & strMsg & "'" & ")</script>"
        Page.Controls.Add(lbl)
End Sub

Comment: Protected Sub Page_Load(..
        Dim sSql As String = "SELECT..."
       If IsPostBack = True Then
          'post
                SqlData.SelectParameters("Course").DefaultValue = "%" & sSubject & "%"
                SqlData.SelectCommand = sSql
                SqlData.DataBind()
                Repeater1.DataSourceID = "SqlData"
                Repeater1.DataBind()
                  Else
            'init
            Dim sm As ScriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me.Page)
            sm.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Repeater1)
        End If
End Sub